# Wi-Fi подключен но интернета нет только на одном ноутбуке

Tags: wifi, ноутбук

Есть ноутбук Acer E5-575G-56PR. Windows 10.
Проблема в том что он подключается к Wi-Fi. Но на сайты не заходит. Ни в одном браузере. Сам интернет и роутер исправны - работают на ПК, смартфоне и ещё 3 ноутбуках. Думал это из-за обновления винды - откатился, проблема осталась. Что ещё может быть не так?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что Видеть мы не можем, да и это не формат для SO.

Comment: Все что угодно. от неправильного пароля на WiFi (да, он при этом подключается, но не работает), до каких то проблем в сетевом стеке, драйверами, вирусами или антивирусами

Comment: @Mike Если бы был неправильный пароль он бы не подключался вообще. Антивирус ESET - все защиты отключил. Обновил драйвер адаптера для wifi - не помогло. Фигня в том что к роутеру подключено 6 устройств и все работают. Пробовали даже на двух разных роутерах и разных интернетах - не работает.

Comment: @Tsyklop В 80% случаев не рабочий интернет именно проблема в пароле. подключение при неправильном пароле на винде часто проходит ! подключите ноут к роутеру кабелем. посмотрите назначает ли ip. есть ли принятые-отправленные пакеты. попингуйте роутер по ip. попингуйте что то в интернете по ip (что бы убедится, что проблема не в dns. Еще можно дать пару сотен вопросов, что надо бы проверить. дистанционно такие проблемы не решаются

Comment: @Mike, но Вы же пытаетесь :)

Comment: @Mike это точно не роутер. У меня ПК соединён кабелем и ещё + 3 ноута по wifi и смартфон и у них всё супер работает. Тут дело в ноуте. Попробую с паролем. Ещё заметил что когда подключаешься он сначала пишет что интернета нет и желтый значок возле wifi. Но потом через время пропадает.

Comment: А я и не говорил что с роутером. я предложил попробовать кабелем подключить _от роутера_, что бы узнать проблема только на WiFi карте ноута или целиком в сетевом стеке винды.